# c# how to find a number position in range

Tags: c#, numbers, position, range

I have found the prime numbers from 2 to 100 for example. I need to know which number is on position let's say 24. Can you help me to find the most simple way to do that?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class SomePrimesRange
{
    static void Main()
    {

        for (int i = 2; i < 260; i++)
        {
            if (i % 2 == 0)
            {

            }
            else if (i % i == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
            }
            List<int> numbers = new List<int>(260);
            numbers.Add(i);
            foreach (int a in numbers)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter a position:");
                int position = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine(position);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Can you help me to find the most simple way to do that?` Of course, just show your hard way so that we can work on it.

Comment: Hi! I have tried to do something like this:
[http://pastebin.com/LPER5CNq] this is my hard way so far :(

Answer (score 0):

First off I'm assuming you don't want a simple solution, cause that would be brute force, and would result in slow unoptimized code.

I'm not going to write code for you, but I will explain the theory behind this and give you some pseudo-code.

```
func findPrimeNumber(int n){
  primeArray = []
  int number = 1

  while(primeArray.length < n){
    if(isNumberPrime(number) == true){
      primeArray.append(number, primeArray)
    }
    number++
  }
}

func isNumberPrime(int number, int[] primeArray){
  var minCheck = Math.roundUp(Math.sqrt(number))
  foreach prime in primeArray{
    if(prime <= minCheck && prime > 1){
     if(number % prime != 0){
       //keep checking numbers
     }else{
       return false  
     }
    }else{
      break; //no more checking is necessary
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

I implemented two basic concepts in the above pseudo-code (you may have to enhance the code for edge cases).

Running an algorithm that determines if a number is prime simply by checking from 2...n-1 is not efficient, and wasteful.

1. You only need to check numbers up to the square root of your number your checking in question rounded up. For instance to determine if 16 is prime, you only need to check if 2, 3, 4 are prime. (answer is yes in the form of 2 and 4).

How about 17? 2,3,4,5 are not divisible and 17 is prime.

2. You only need to check prime factors. There is no point in checking if a number is prime by dividing it by non-prime numbers since every non-prime is composed of primes eventually. So you only need to check the prime factors that are less than the square root.

In terms of determining the 24th iteration, there may be a dynamic programming solution that is more intelligent than mine, but I simply linearly look for the first 24 primes, but optimize the looking process so that will be fast.

Let me know if you need any more help. Good luck, fun little problem.

Comment: @John Thompson Was this able to help?

Answer (score 0):

Do a foreach loop . Add the numbers to a list. Then get the 24th item in the array. Item[23](not item[24] because a array starts at 0]

This is the Code for this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace PrimeNumberHelp
{
    class Program
    {

        private static int Max = 100;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<int> Primes = new List<int>();
            int current = 0;
            while (current <= 100)
            {
                if (IsPrime(current))
                    Primes.Add(current);
                current++;
            }
            Console.WriteLine(Primes[23]);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static bool IsPrime(int number)
        {
            if (number == 1)
                return false;
            if (number == 2)
                return true;

            if (number % 2 == 0)
                return false;

            for (int i = 3; i * i <= number; i += 2)
            {
                if (number % i == 0)
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am doing this really wrong. Can you help me a bit please? I am new to C# and I thought that something like this will do it:
[http://pastebin.com/LPER5CNq]
but no :(

Comment: @TsenkoAleksiev Did this help? If so ,select this as a answer.